# How properly assign singleton to a variable in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I have a project written in `Objective-C`. Inside it I use `singleton`.

Its declaration is:

```
+ (id)sharedInstance
{
    static id sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

I init it inside each class where I use it by this code:

```
singApp = [XXXsingApplication sharedInstance];
```

When I run *Xcode Analyzer* I get following *warning*:

> Instance variable used while 'self' is not set to the result of
>   '[(super or self) init...]'

Why I get this *warning*?

I suppose I have some general misunderstanding of matter, because AFAIK it has only single instance and must not be init again to avoid creating several instances?

**EDIT:**

My `init` looks like:

```
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    // init read-only values
    _appSwVersion = APP_SOFT_VERSION;
    _appSwDateTime = APP_SOFT_DATETIME;
    _websDns = WEBS_DNS;
    _testWebsUrl = TEST_WEBS_DNS_URL;

    // init properties dictionary
    _propListDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    @try {

        if (self) {

            // load settings
            [self loadSettingsFromFile];

            // init custom Bundle
            [self setCustomBundle];
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"EXCEPTION\nName-> %@\nDescription-> %@", [exception name], [exception description]);
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: `sharedInstance = [[XXXsingApplication alloc] init];`?

Comment: What does your `init` method look like?

Comment: Also, you should use `instancetype`, not `id`, for the return type.

Comment: I don't understand @Larme? I need to make init inside other methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceptions are there to catch programming errors. You don't catch and handle exceptions in Objective-C. When an exception happens, you let it crash. This is Objective-C, not Java or C++. You don't handle exceptions, you fix the code.

You should check whether self == nil *immediately* after calling [super init]. Think about what you are doing: You are assigning to an instance variable which will lead to a crash if self == nil. Sure, there will be cases where people are 100% sure that self cannot be nil. But five lines later, you check whether self == nil. That combination is a **clear indication of a bug**. If you check, you must check before you assign to an instance variable. If you assign to an instance variable, any check is too late.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like this.

```
 -(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    @try {

        if (self) {

            // init read-only values
            _appSwVersion = APP_SOFT_VERSION;
            _appSwDateTime = APP_SOFT_DATETIME;
            _websDns = WEBS_DNS;
            _testWebsUrl = TEST_WEBS_DNS_URL;

            // init properties dictionary
            _propListDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            // load settings
            [self loadSettingsFromFile];

            // init custom Bundle
            [self setCustomBundle];
        }
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"EXCEPTION\nName-> %@\nDescription-> %@", [exception name], [exception description]);
    }

    return self;
}
```